# Tem como usar if para os endereços de um array?

Tags: php

O que eu quero fazer com o **PHP** é com que cada endereço de um array seja comparado se é >= 100 por exemplo não sei se funciona **if ([0]..[4] >= 100)** existe uma forma de comparar todos os valores de endereços com um if ? ou se tiver algo semelhante agradeço (ps : Já pequisei bastante e não achei)bom gente agradeço todos pela ajuda consegui resolver o problema

Comment: Pesquise por array_filter

Comment: `array_filter` me parece bastante desnecessário em algo tão simples, geralmente pode-se resolver dentro do mesmo `for...` se a intenção não for reaproveitar a array para outra coisa, por exemplo salvar este array em um arquivo, banco ou outro formato (como até um xml, resumindo, guardar os dados), na pratica quase sempre será uso de recurso desnecessário para executar algo que muitas vezes acaba sendo executado duas vezes. Claro que não estou dizendo que a função é inútil, estou dizendo que o uso dela para coisas assim as vezes acaba sendo um exagero.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se quiser aplicar um `if` em um intervalo uso um laço mesmo.

```
for($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
    if($array[$i] >= 100) {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Como sugerido pelo [Anderson Carlos Woss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) nos comentários, a função:

**[`array_filter ( array $array \[, callable $callback \[, int $flag = 0 \]\] ) : array`](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.array-filter.php)**

Filtra elementos de um array utilizando uma função callback. Iterando sobre cada valor de array passando-os para a função callback. Se a função callback retornar true, o valor atual de array é retornado na matriz resultado.

```
<?php
$numeros = [-25, -16, -9, -4, 0 , 4 , 9 , 16, 25];

echo "Números:" . PHP_EOL;
print_r($numeros);

// Filtra os valores maiores que 0
$positivos = array_filter($numeros, function ($val) {return $val > 0;} );

echo "Números positivos:" . PHP_EOL;
print_r($positivos);

// Aplica a função sqrt(), raíz quadrada, aos valores positivos previamente filtrados
$raizes = array_map('sqrt', $positivos );

echo "Raízes dos números positivos:" . PHP_EOL;
print_r($raizes);
```

[Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/StrangeClientsideCarrier)